# PHP variable to node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, localhost

I manage my webpage with php, and as soon I login I want to pass a PHP variable to my `index.ejs` file.

```
<textarea id="inputText" class="base--textarea input--text-area" placeholder="Please enter text to analyze...">
<?php 
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['description'];
?> 
</textarea>
```

Now, when I run nodejs `app.js`, in localhost 3000, node reads it as plain text.How can I pass the values that I login into my node app.

Comment: I'm not really getting what you're trying to do. Are you trying to read the php-file with nodejs?

Comment: yes,to pass the php var description wich I take from login to the nodejs app

Comment: so php is installed and being used by node or what? i dont think something is being used correctly here. php has to process the file before node serves it to your browser and that process wouldn't be trivial to set up.

Comment: do you have code that's more relevant to the question? it's hard to figure what you're trying to do

Comment: Node can't parse and run PHP files. That would require Node to start a PHP engine and that would just be... well...  wrong! Even if it for some reason could, I doubt it would be able to pass sessions and variables. Either do your app in PHP or Node.

Comment: PHP can be and is (that's how the web server serves the php content) interpreted by the operating system that hosts it.  As such, Node CAN initiate the PHP interpreter and interpret the php file.  However, this won't work, if I'm understanding.   It seems like the OP wants to post text to the PHP file and have Node know about it.  To achieve this, you'd need some sort of interprocess mechanism to pass the value from the PHP session to the running node session.   This could happen with something like php's Curl command.   But it's not a trivial thing to do.

Comment: @RayWadkins I want it for my master theisis so its ok,do you know any examples of this?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I know I have searched for this,there are some examples that you can pass cookies but that only works in mozilla

Comment: @VladimirP, sadly I don't.  But curl lets you connect to http interfaces and get documents or post or put data.   since your node process is listening on port localhost:3000, code in your PHP script can post data as if it was a browser. There are many other types of interprocess communication out there, which may be worth looking into.  However, since node is already listening to that port (I assume as an http(s?) server) you've got an interface built in.

Comment: @RayWadkins - cURL simply makes a tcp-request. That's it! PHP isn't "interprocessed" by the operating system. What happens is: A web server gets a request to a PHP-file, if the web server is set up to handle PHP, the **web server** starts the PHP-interpreter, which interprets and executes the PHP-code and then returns the results to the web server, which returns it to the client .Using cURL, you need to create a web service in PHP which you call from node. That's not node "reading or interpreting" a PHP file. That's just node calling a web service, which could be written in any language.

Comment: how about passing a javascript var from localhost to localhost:3000?from one server to another,if i start my session inside  a js file and include it to my other .ejs file it should work?!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson,@RayWadkins do you know any example of using personality insight with php,the only one I've found is 2 years old and outdated!,,,that would help

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you completely misinterpreted my suggestion.  PHP can POST to the webserver created by NODE (an assumption from the OP's post).   PHP has a curl library that speaks http (in addition to other protocols).   client posts to PHP, php proxies the post to node.   Simple.   Well, for some.  As for interprocess, the php interpeter is process 1, node is process 2.  communication between them is "inter", wether by file, pipe or http(tcp).

Comment: @VladimirP, sorry, never heard of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.get('/search.html', function(req, res) {
    // Process the request for the GET variables
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var query = url_parts.query; // These are all your GET variables
    var search_keyword = query.keyword;

    if(search_keyword) {
        // The keyword indeed exists
        console.log(search_keyword);

    }
    res.end();
});
```

Here's how I do it:

Create a new ExpressJS app
If you run the app and go to "search.html?keyword=haha", your console will output "haha". You can do anything after that with the keyword.

Comment: Thanks for the help!